# How to read geopackage file with FID column using rgdal in R

Tags: r, rgdal, geopackage

I have a points vector layer saved in geopackage format (gpkg). I loaded it to R using `rgdal` library. The problem is I can't get attributes table with `fid` column (unique feature identifier).

```
library(rgdal)
points <- readOGR("dist_points.gpkg")
df_points_1 <- points@data
df_points_2 <- as.data.frame(points)
```

Both of the above methods don't work. 
Here are examples:

QGIS:
[image: QGIS]

R:
[image: R]

As you can see the `fid` column is missing. It even states that while loading data:

```
OGR data source with driver: GPKG 
Source: "dist_points.gpkg", layer: "dist_points"
with 19 features
It has 8 fields
```

"It has 8 fileds" but there are 9. How can I get the `fid` column as well?

Here is sample gpkg file: [dist_points.gpkg](https://www.pastefile.com/tGhYCV)

Comment: Have you seen the `fid_column_name` argument? https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_read.html#arguments

Comment: Yes, this is working, although it is different package. But I need it only for this purpose so thank You.